# Session management in tab and new window of same browser in Spring mvc web app

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC , Spring security and jsp for my web application.

Now my problem is:

When an user logs-in  to the application and if he  opens a tab or a new window of the same  browser then the current logged in user should automatically logs-in in the tab or new window like Gmail or Yahoo.

Please help me in this problem.

Thanks
Gyan

Answer (score 0):

That would be default behavior if you are using cookies for session tracking,

Browser itself takes care of putting right cookie depending on the requested path

Comment: Hi, Its not happening by default if I need to write any code to do such please let me know.